# 0 I am having issues with Command swift driver. 1)Command SwiftDriver emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am having issues with Command swift driver.

1)Command SwiftDriver emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure

2. Unexpected input file: /Users/surayafarhanaabdulnasser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gout_Mangement_App_Trial_1_7.33.11

3)Unknown dynamically requested build input cannot be found. enter image description here

I was trying to run the app after copying certain files, but ail an error shows as per below: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/js8nQ.jpg)